# Can't understand how to use Django external apps -> example clarle/django-slides

Tags: jquery, python, django

### **I need short discription - HOW to run this app locally... Just few steps, but then after I finished them all, my app would run!**

Can't understand how to use Django external apps, especially,

https://github.com/clarle/django-slides

1) I downloaded it.

2) Opened inside a project.

3) Made such things:

- added to INSTALLED APPS
- added a template that extends base.html

  ```
  {% extends 'slideshow\base.html' %}
  {% load slideshow_tags %}   
  {% block body %}
  {% place_slides Kolka %}
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- Made url pattern and view:

  ```
  def index(request):
      Kolka = get_object_or_404(Slideshow, id=1)
      context = {'Kolka': Kolka}
      return render(request, 'slideshow/index.html', context)

  urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^$', 'slideshow.views.index', name='home'),)
  ```
- Added 'Kolka' slideshow with the admin page.

As a result, index page works, but pictures are not displayed as well as Description and name of the slide.

I think, problem is because settings  are not correct for

```
 - STATIC_ROOT = '' 

 - STATIC_URL = '/static/' 

 - STATICFILES_DIRS = ( )
```

or something else...

### **I need short discription - HOW to run this app locally... Just few steps, but then after I finished them all, my app would run!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to setup your static configurations
this is the link which explains how to do it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/

Comment: I try to read about static. And I did not have problems with my own apps. But, when I try to do this with slides, everything crashes...(

Comment: this app Slideshow saves images to its directory. Not throuhg static, just in current directory, and when I run the server, it can't see these files, but the url path to image is correct

Comment: add aplications static dir to STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: thanks.http://prntscr.com/1nk7g4                             http://prntscr.com/1nk7d6   I am trying to say, that this APP saves images not to static. In 'models.py', in class Slide, ImageField saves picture TO folder "slideshow" - > current app'sdirectory.

Comment: Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a particular app. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files. For example:

<code>STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
)</code>

Comment: can you post apps models.py

Comment: change the upload_to='/slideshow/' to upload_to='your direcoty'

Comment: What directory it should be?

Comment: i usually keep it in my 'mainapp'/static/img/ . you can put it anywhere you want. the put the full path to that dir in STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: post your full path where you set upload_to, STATICFILES_DIR